# .Net Framework difference?

Tags: .net

what are the differences in terms of features in .Net frameworks 1.1,2.0,3.0 and 3.5?

Comment: Perhapse MSDN and the Microsoft .NET product pages would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 12):

Please read [.NET Framework - Versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions).  Most specifically these sections:

> - [Changes in 1.1 on comparison with 1.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Changes_in_1.1_on_comparison_with_1.0)
> - [Changes in 2.0 in comparison with 1.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Changes_in_2.0_in_comparison_with_1.1)
> - [Changes since version 3.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Changes_since_version_3.0)

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I recall the progression:

v1.0 -- Holy God, this should really be called a BETA

v1.1 -- Oh, that's better, now it works correctly most of the time.

v2.0 -- What's that, you really just wanted to add Garbage Collection to C++ and limit Multiple Inheritance.

v3.0 -- WPF, WCF, WF -- OMFG, you want me to learn a whole new set of APIs to do exactly the same thing I just learned?  Are you kidding me?

v3.5 --  LINQ (to SQL in particular) -- Oh great, what's that make 6 different data access technologies in the past 10 years?  Come on, lets all just learn Python or Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia seems to have the best overview of the framework changes from 1.0 to 3.5:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions

MSDN Also has an overview for each framework version:

v1.1
Highlights: Side by side execution, security enhancements, IPv6 support
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wtde3k4.aspx

v2.0
Highlights: 64-Bit support, Generics, System.IO.Compression, Many More (Huge Update)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t357fb32.aspx

v3.0
Highlights: Windows Communication, Workflow, and Presentation foundations
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822048.aspx

v3.5
Highlights: HashSet, Linq Introduction, Expression Trees
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332048.aspx

v3.5 SP1
Highlights: DataRepeater control, WPF performance improvements
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713697.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here a similar blog that shows the [Differences and added features from .NET Framework 1.1 and on](http://dufoli.wordpress.com/2007/09/11/net-framework-11-20-30-35-21/)

**.NET framework 1.0 :**

This is the first release of the .NET Framework, released on 13 February 2002 and available for Windows 98, Me, NT 4.0, 2000, and XP.

**.NET framework 1.1 :**

This is the first version of the .NET Framework to be included as part of the Windows operating system, shipping. The .NET Framework version 1.1 extends the .NET Framework version 1.0 with new features, improvements to existing features, and enhancements to the documentation.

**.NET framework 2.0:**

It is bring a lot of evolution in class of the framework and refactor some control.
The other big evolution here is on language with support of :

```
* generics
* anonymous methods
* partial class
* nullable type
* …
```

**.NET framework 3.0:**

This framework is the key for developing application under Vista.
It is just a set of assembly which use XML to map:

```
* Communication (WCF)
* View (WPF)
* Workflow (WWF)
* Digital identity (CardSpace)
```

The framework is still the .NET framework2.0 behind it.
For a lot of developer this is not a real framework.

**.NET framework 3.5:**

It implement Linq evolution in language. So we have the folowing evolution in class:

```
* Linq for SQL, XML, Dataset, Object
* Addin system
* p2p base class
* Active directory
* ASP.NET Ajax
```

Answer (score 1):

Features!

- In 2.0, the big feature was generics.
- In 3.0, the big features were WPF, WCF and WWF
- In 3.5, the big feature was Linq

In all versions, there are tons more features, but these, in my mind were the biggest tags.

Answer (score 1):

*If you want a serious answer to this question, you would check the Microsoft Website, Wikipedia, or the other questions on SO that ask the same thing. Here're my two cents...*

Let's see... version 1.x, Microsoft seemed poised to take over all platforms at all moments in all languages. Mono was looking promising for other platforms, and it was a pretty exciting moment. I was proud to develop on Windows!

When MS .Net 2.0 came out, Mono was in a stable, good state, but it was obviously going to lag one version behind Microsoft .Net forever. It was obvious that Microsoft not only wasn't going to support Mono, but was involved in a series of lawsuits with Novell. Do they put cash into Mono development?

Now 3.5 is out, and it's clear: if you're not developing for Windows (that is, your deployment platform is Windows) and you're not a Mono enthusiast (there are millions, but I think there are 10x as many Java people as Mono-based .Net devs), you no longer care about .Net whatsoever.

So basically, Microsoft was poised to take over the world for the second time, but they decided that selling Windows was more important than one-platform-to-rule-them-all. And they may be right... they've got enough cash to still do something very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions) has a pretty good listing of the differences between versions.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework).  You also need to add 4.0 to your list as well...